# Need to create a view that gets me the same results without a subquery in the from clause

Tags: mysql

This query gives me exactly the data I want

```
SELECT Sales Number, Percentage Complete, Date, Scheduled Completion
FROM (SELECT `Sales Number`, `Date`, `Percentage Complete`, `Scheduled Completion` 
      FROM Details 
      ORDER BY `Date` DESC) AS A
GROUP BY `Sales Number`
```

The code generator I'm using doesn't allow me to join it to another view as it is (which I need to do.) If I could save a view that would give me the same results, I'd be good to go.

I've tried breaking out the subqueries to make two separate views, but the results are not the same. (I need only the latest entry for each `Sales Number`.)

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You started off by saying that the query gives you exactly the data that you want. Why do you need to change it?

Comment: Since the SELECT has a subquery in the FROM clause, I can't save it as a VIEW. In order to JOIN it to another VIEW, (which I need to do,) I need to have a VIEW that gives me the same results as the above code.

Comment: That query gives you the results you expect because of a quirk in MySQL.  It is not fundamentally correct, however, because `GROUP BY` does not determinstically return the value of a specific row for non-aggregated columns.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I guess that's why I can't recreate the results without the subquery. This seems like it should be way more simple than I'm making it. All I need is the most recent row data for each `Sales Number`. Something like SELECT `Percentage Complete`, `Scheduled Completion` FROM `Details` WHERE `Date` = MAX(`Date`) GROUP BY `Sales Number`. Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, solved it myself!
My second working query is able to be broken down into to two VIEWS..

I first created a VIEW called `test` from this query:

```
Select `Sales Number`,max(`Date`) as `Date`
From `Details`
Group By `Sales Number`
```

Then I created another view called `latest` from this query:

```
Select q.`Date`,
d.`Sales Number`,
d.`Percentage Complete`,
d.`Scheduled Completion`
From `Details` As `d`
Inner Join `test` As `q`
On d.`Sales Number` = q.`Sales Number`
And d.`Date` = q.`Date`
```

I'm now able to LEFT JOIN it to another table in my code generator, and it produces the desired results.  It's probably not the most efficient way to do it, so any improvements are certainly appreciated.

Comment: Even though there are not that many records in the `Details` table (1235,) the above code is far too slow for practical use.

Comment: This code above worked but it was so slow that I needed a better way to gather the data. I found that I could get the latest data by injecting it into the fields of the MASTER table whenever the DETAILS table was updated. For anyone interested, I used the following code to do it: global $conn;
$strSQLInsert = "UPDATE `Property Details Complete` SET `Percentage Complete`= ".$values["Percentage Complete"].",
`Scheduled Completion`= '".$values["Scheduled Completion"]."'
where `Sales Number`= ".$values["Sales Number"]." " ; db_exec($strSQLInsert,$conn);

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot more searching and trial & error (mostly error,) I figured out that this query also gives me the desired results, but once again, it cannot be saved as a VIEW because it has a SELECT in the FROM clause.

```
   Select q.`Date`,
   d.`Sales Number`,
   d.`Percentage Complete`,
   d.`Scheduled Completion`
   From `Details` As `d`
   Inner Join (
   Select `Sales Number`,max(`Date`) as `Date`
   From `Details`
   Group By `Sales Number`) As `q`
   On d.`Sales Number` = q.`Sales Number`
   And d.`Date` = q.`Date`
```

Can anyone please put me out of my misery on this?